# How to check installed package versions of deployed React application?

Tags: reactjs, azure, material-ui, web-deployment, react-boilerplate

We used react-boilerplate to create and application. And we've used material-ui as the UI library and hosted on Azure IIS.

Due to a recent material-ui package release, somethings are breaking on local environment and not in the deployed application. I just want to make sure if it's just in the dev environment or deployed react app uses a previous package.json version to make sure npm install won't break the deployed application.
(The package.json file in wwwroot folder shows the express server package.json, but I want to find the react application package.json or versions)

So, how can I find the *package.json* file of the deployed application ? Or how can I check the installed versions (package-lock.json or npm ls) ?

**TLDR :** 
How to get the installed package versions of deployed react application (on *Azure IIS*)?

Answer (score 0):

`package.json` is used during build to choose dependencies to install for the project. This file does not exist in the deployed files. If you go to Advanced Tools tab on your app service and then click on `Tools>Zip Push Deploy`, you will see all files on your deployed website. You will not find package.json there as it is only present before the build process.

The only way for you to find the package.json file for your deployment build is if you are using CI/CD, then you can go to `Deployment Center` tab on your app service, click on the latest build link and see the branch from which the build was triggered. You will find the package.json file in that branch. If the branch has been modified after the build was deployed, you can check history of that branch and choose package.json as on the date of deployment.

If you are not using CI/CD, then you are out of luck.